# tabgroup in android merge in action bar in landscape in titanium

Tags: android, android-actionbar, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have added the tabgroup in android and when i rotate the phone in landscape then it merge in action bar. I do not want to merge it with action bar and it should display under the action bar.

Comment: I have tried few things, but could not achieve what you want.
But to overcome this situation, in one of my app I am using manual tabs with ScrollableView which has in-built horizontal swipe support even for iOS and it works perfectly. You will need to use [scrollend event of ScrollableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-event-scrollend)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is native behaviour for [ActionBar.Tab](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.Tab.html) which is what we [currently use](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/widget/tabgroup/TiUIActionBarTabGroup.java#L117-L118) for the TabGroup. However, these are deprecated so we'll have to switch to something else.

This might be a good moment to file a new feature request/improvement. Include an example of a (builtin) Android app which has the behaviour you are looking for when you create a ticket on [JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org)